# get the value from an object array base on its sub array directly

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

First, I have this multi dimensional array.

```
$array = array("user1" => array("name" => "Jason", "category" => "health"),
               "user2" => array("name" => "Mechelle", "category" => "Politics"));
```

how can I retrieved the sub array's value base on its same sub array object without using a loop? like I want to get the value of the array object named "name" from the object array named "category" that has a value of health. My expected result is "Jason" because in the array where the array object named "name" that has a value of 'Jason' belongs to a same sub array named 'category' where the value is "health". Any help, ideas, clues, recommendations, suggestions please?

Comment: without a loop? why? what's wrong with using a loop? and what loop are you referring? `foreach`?

Comment: Will yes, surely I can use foreach as its a common way of getting the value and much easier and simplified, I just taking a way if its possible to get the value directly without looping.

Comment: No, there isn't any way to do it. The only direct way to access array elements is by the index. If you want to be able to access an element by category, you should make that the index of the array.

Comment: if you want a crowbar to hit a nail or use a laudry machine to clean the dishes, you can try regex, encode it a json string then create your pattern and get the matches

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without explicit loops. `array_filter` and `array_reduce` to the rescue! The following assumes that your initial array will be much larger and will probably include multiple sub-arrays with a category of "health."

```
$array = array(
    "user1" => array("name" => "Jason", "category" => "health"),
    "user2" => array("name" => "Mechelle", "category" => "Politics")
);

$healthUsers = array_filter($array, function($user) {
    return $user["category"] === "health";
});

$names = array_reduce($healthUsers, function($carry, $user) {
    $carry .= $user["name"] . " ";
    return $carry;
});

echo $names . PHP_EOL;
```

`array_filter` gives us a smaller array that only contains users which have a "category" of "health."

`array_reduce` runs through that array, extracts the names of each user, and puts it in a space-delimited string.